# Spring Boot application runs fine via Maven but not via IDE Intellij IDEA

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have a spring boot application which runs fine via Maven's `mvn spring-boot:run` command. However, when I try to run it through the IDE, which is Intellij IDEA 2017.2.1 in my case, it fails because it could not `@Autowire` a data source.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.myApp.Application required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.
```

The original authors of this code base have the main class, which starts the application, accepting constructor arguments for the data source, an approach I am unfamiliar with as I am used to just doing it through the `application.properties` file and letting Spring Boot wire up it's own DataSource.

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class Application extends JpaBaseConfiguration {


    protected Application(DataSource dataSource, JpaProperties properties,
            ObjectProvider<JtaTransactionManager> jtaTransactionManagerProvider,
            ObjectProvider<TransactionManagerCustomizers> transactionManagerCustomizers) {
        super(dataSource, properties, jtaTransactionManagerProvider, transactionManagerCustomizers);
    }
```

In IDEA, I've noticed that the `datasource` and the `properties` arguments to this constructor are underlined in red. For `datasource` the IDE is complaining that two beans exist and it doesn't know which to autowire between `XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.class` and `DataSourceConfiguration.class`. As for the other argument to the construction which is underlined in red, `properties`, it can't find any beans, the IDE complains that no bean of type `JpaProperties` is found. Here are some other methods which are overridden in the main application starter class,

```
        @Override
        protected AbstractJpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter() {
            return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        }


        @Override
        protected Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties() {
            Map<String, Object> vendorProperties = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            vendorProperties.putAll(getProperties().getHibernateProperties(getDataSource()));
            return vendorProperties;
        }


        public static void main(final String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);


}
```

Unfortunately, because I am not familiar with this approach of using the constructor to configure/auto-configure the application in Spring Boot, I am unsure of a few things, but my exact question is why does the application run fine with Maven but not in Intellij IDEA? Moreover, since I don't have access to the original authors to this proprietary code base, I'd love to know why, if anyone can even give me a hint, they have configured the constructor as such as opposed to default autoconfiguration. I also have an integration test which I wrote that I am trying to run but this test, whether run through the IDE or via Maven's failsafe plugin also results in the same error with the `DataSource` not being `@Autowired`. So this is another question as to why this test won't run through Maven when the main application will. Here's my integration test,

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = TransactionController.class, secure = false)
public class TransactionControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void shouldInitiateTransfer() {

        String transferTransaction =
              "some json string I can't show here on stack overflow";

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("/begin-transfer")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(transferTransaction)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MvcResult result = null;

        try {
            result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail("Exception in integration test!");
        }

        MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED.value(), response.getStatus());

    }
}
```

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test is failing because it's using a slice test, `@WebMvcTest` these tests (`@DataJpaTest`, `JsonTest`) only loads a small part of the overall application context rather than everything that the application does on startup or a (`@SpringBootTest`) would.

When using a slice test it will use any annotations, and require any beans, defined within the `@SpringBootApplication` class.

E.g. because you have autowired beans defined and and two additional annotations for any slice test caching and transaction management will be enabled and it will always require these dependencies passed.

I would not make your main application class extend a configuration class in this way, it's overly complex and smells like XY problem. You should externalize configurations (and Enable annotations) to their own `@Configuration` class and leave the `@SpringBootApplication` as vanilla a possible to avoid these sort of errors.

Comment: Thanks for the informative response. Would you be able to show me what annotations would make my integration test work? I tried SpringBootTest but now the autowired MockMvc is null. Also, given the current configuration, can you advise as to what I could do to get the project to run in the IDE?

Comment: Unsure about the IDE issue. You should be able to use a combination of `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=MOCK)` and `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`. There is also a fallback that you could use and use a `MockMvcBuilder` and create it yourself via passing controllers or  the web application context. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/setup/MockMvcBuilders.html

Answer (score 6):

You can easily run any Spring Boot app from IDEA doing the following:

[image]

In Maven panel, go to Plugins, unfold spring-boot and right-click on "spring-boot:run". Then click on "Create your-project..." as shown in the image.

This way you can just start the application in a comfortable way from IDEA from the main toolbar:

[image]

This way you are still using the maven way, but integrated in IDEA. I don't really know why are you having those problems. I also experience some problems when trying to execute the spring boot app directly.

Comment: I have actually resorted to doing just that, I've created a Maven run configuration in IDEA because IDEA wouldn't run the application natively. I'd still love to know why it won't run in IDEA though.