# Application Running via Spring Boot Run but not via IntelliJ Idea

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I am facing the issue where when I am running my spring boot application via Command line

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Dserver.port=8083"
```

This works fine, but running as Application in intellij I am getting below errors -

```
Application run failed,
exc.stack=org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: 
Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException:

Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.\n\tat org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
```

What can be the possible reasons, and where should I look into configurations fixes?

There are other questions on this pattern, but none of them have mentioned the error -

[Spring Boot application runs fine via Maven but not via IDE Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45737164/spring-boot-application-runs-fine-via-maven-but-not-via-ide-intellij-idea)

[ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231736/applicationcontextexception-unable-to-start-servletwebserverapplicationcontext/50232382)
(For missing servlet bean, but if this is the case, then app should not have started via command line too)

So, I could not find any answer there.

Comment: Have you checked this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231736 
Seems similar

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov Yes, I have attached this link in question too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error could occur when you have Tomcat's dependency scope as "provided", but while running the application, you are not choosing the option "Include dependencies with provided scope".

You could select that option under the Run Configuration for your app.

In some older versions of IntelliJ, you might see a checkbox to enable the same.

[image: Options in Run Configuration IntelliJ]

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer provided by @Ankit Raj, in the IntelliJ Idea 2022.3.1.

The option here is `Add dependencies with "provided" scope to classpath`

As shown in the

[image: Screen shot of the]